# Is there a way to change lookandfeel for wx Python?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

i was curious if there is some sort of way to change the look and feel of wxpython to something that is more standardized. I am writing a small application for windows and mac os x. And i noticed that Mac formats the layout and look of my application pretty terribly. I looked around online and could not find anything. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post screenshots of Windows and Mac versions?

Comment: I don't think i would be allowed, i am unsure of what my work's stance would be. However the most major thing is, certain elements do not appear to have their colors changed. E.g. We change a buttons color from red to green, to try to catch the users attention. However in mac it just keeps the default theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://old.nabble.com/wxPython-Themes-Colors-td20337650.html:

> Not really.  The default colors are always the platform and/or theme
>   defaults, but some things can be changed by setting the colors of the
>   parent window before creating the children.  Not everything works that
>   way however, such as things that use a different setting from the theme
>   than the standard bg or fg color, such as the background color of
>   listbox or textctrl.